# Add custom arrow to Zurb-Foundation drop-down buttons

Tags: drop-down-menu, grid, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I created a button using Zurb Foundation styles and Sass mixins. I used `@include dropdown-button($base-style:false);` to get rid of the default arrow style. Now I want to insert my own arrow in its place (right side)

Here is the default button:

[image: default]

Here is my button now:

[image: current]

I want mine to look something like this:

[image: final]

Here is my html:

```
<a class="login width-limit" href="#" data-dropdown="drop">Client_Test_1 </a><br>
      <ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Change SMTP Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Here is my scss:

```
.login {
  @include grid-column(2);
  @include button();
  @include dropdown-button($base-style:false);
  font-family: $font-stack;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  height: 27px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 6px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 4px 5px 4px;
}
.width-limit {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right: 2em; //shrink text 
}
.login:hover {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5uU/

How can I add my own custom arrow to make it look like the third example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the buttons are sized appropriately for your grid, won't making them large enough to fit the text make them *not* fit into your grid anymore?

Comment: @cimmanon Yes that is true, perhaps there is a way to make the button not a part of the top header and somehow be responsive to the name length. I've updated my question with code. Let me know what you think?

Comment: That's how Foundation  makes buttons with arrows https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_dropdown-buttons.scss  look at `@mixin dropdown-button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it infinitely long and not break page layout. So simple solution will be deciding how long it can get and setting button container to fill maximum amount of columns before it starts to look wired. Then you can align your button inside the container as you wish and if it gets too long you can replace part of the name with "**...**" css:`overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;` or show the short form with js.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/z8aWL/2/

Comment: Thanks, I really like your solution although I'm not completely sure how to implement it. I've included the code and a jsfiddle in my question could you help me out?

Comment: Thanks! I've almost got it working perfect. The problem is that when I have 14 characters it still slighty overlaps with the dropdown arrow, but anything over 14 characters then the ... fixes it. How can I make it so that the ... comes in sooner? Here is currently what my code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/QM8Kp/ Thanks!

Comment: @MattCamp http://jsfiddle.net/FvRER/ use `padding-right` in the `width-limit` to shrink it.

Comment: @MattCamp also you can move little arrow with `:after` selector and `top` `left` properties.

Comment: I've tried both of those solutions, but yet the text still overlaps the arrow. I'm not sure how the :after selector works, because the arrow is part of foundations styles. Is there a way to make the text stop sooner and the ... start?

Comment: That solution is perfect, but something else in my code must be messing with the :after selector. I added the exact code in your fiddle, but my arrow will not move! I've included every bit of my code  in this fiddle so perhaps you can help me find what is causing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/42hY9/

Comment: @MattCamp try adding !important and raising specificity http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work... I've added some edits to the bottom of my question. Let me know if you can help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yet it still does not work for me... In my struggle I decided to just start over and try again from scratch. I got pretty far and then got stuck. I've changed the question above to match my new problem. Take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The grid column 2 mixin gives you this:

```
width: grid-calc($columns, $total-columns);
```

If you're using the default 12 grid, your inputs look like this:

```
width: grid-calc(2, 12);
```

The calc function returns the percentage of 2 divided by 12

```
width: 16.67%;
```

You are then overwriting that width value with 150px. If you're using default grid values for large rows, that should be closer to 167px wide.

You should avoid setting hard px values if you want to keep this responsive.

Now as for long names, you have two basic options. Either truncate names, by hiding overflow (as JAre suggested) or let crazy long names break your grid, but be contained in the button. Then you would need to not set a width. All the grid col mixin does is give you a width percentage. The row sets the value of the width (of which the col is a percentage). Your button is still contained in a row, so you should be good to go.

I think your best option, if you have access to your username database is to find the "worst case scenario" and design for that. Or better yet, have a shortened name value returned to your design in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @fontophilic. Unfortunately I don't quite understand what you are suggesting that I do. I am very new to the grid and using sass mixins. Sorry for the inconvenience, but could you try and rephrase what you are saying to help me out?

Comment: Hi @MattCamp, I did leave it open ended because I can see multiple good solutions for your problem. 1. Design for the "worst case scenario" 2. truncate names. 3. Let the names show in full. If you want the names to show in full inside the button (as your initial question asks) you need to remove any width restrictions, including the grid mixin.

Comment: Great thanks! @fontophilic, I would like to truncate names, but the issue I'm finding now is that the little arrow on the drop-down is still overlapping with the text. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuYjF/ Is there a way to move the arrow or fix the text so it truncates sooner?

Comment: I would appreciate some help here. In my struggle I decided to just start over and try again from scratch. I got pretty far and then got stuck. I've changed the question above to match my new problem. Take a look. Thanks!